# How to get clang format for Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, plugins, clang-format

After Xcode update to version 8. The very useful Alcatraz PlugIn Manager is locked out and superb utilities like clang-format, or highlight selected word occurrences, or resize the font by use of a shortcut are gone.

How can I reenable clang-format to format my current source code file on save with a template .clang-format in any parent directory of the source file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mapbox/XcodeClangFormat](https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat) extension looks like a promising way to get clang format working with Xcode8.

Due to the limitations of source editor extensions, unfortunately you can only specify one .clang-format file for all your projects. "Format on save" also is not available.

Comment: I tested this and it does what it can do within the tight restrictions of the new Xcode plugin model. What I am missing is 'format on save' which is not possible according to its author. But it is an as-close-as-possible option for an clang-format plugin.

Comment: @VisorZ, perhaps there's a way to combine both osascript and this plugin, in order to override the command Command+S with automation that press the `clang-format` button that trigger the plugin ?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a shell script that is added to Xcode 8 as a behavior: Xcode > Behaviors > +(to create new one) > Run script: (select file here), add shortcut like Cmd+Shift+S.

The script asks Xcode to save the current document. Then it extracts its filepath and calls clang-format to format that file in-place. Clang-format has to be available e.g. by using *brew* as the package manager to download it and having its path published for command line access. As usual the style guide used by clang-format must have the name *.clang-format* and must be in any parent folder of the source file.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CDP=$(osascript -e '
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using {command down}
    --wait for Xcode to remove edited flag from filename
    delay 0.3
    set last_word_in_main_window to (word -1 of (get name of window 1))
    set current_document to document 1 whose name ends with last_word_in_main_window
    set current_document_path to path of current_document
    --CDP is assigned last set value: current_document_path
end tell ')

LOGPATH=$(dirname "$0")
LOGNAME=formatWithClangLog.txt
echo "Filepath: ${CDP}" > ${LOGPATH}/${LOGNAME}
sleep 0.6 ### during save Xcode stops listening for file changes
/usr/local/bin/clang-format -style=file -i -sort-includes ${CDP} >> ${LOGPATH}/${LOGNAME} 2>&1

# EOF
```

Please exchange the path /usr/local/bin to the one where your clang-format executable resides.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Found a viable solution in this blog - [code-beautifier-in-xcode](http://blog.manbolo.com/2015/05/14/code-beautifier-in-xcode)

Basically, we can have [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) running as a service by automator and invoke it through Xcode whenever we need to format the code. Refer the blog for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Alcatraz plug-ins get be back to work in Xcode 8+ when unsigning them. Because I am not in the situation to try that, I can only point you to that resource:

Examine the header *Installation* on that github page [ClangFormat-Xcode](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode).

Comment: I tried after updating to Xcode 9.2. I unsigned my Xcode like it was described on the ClangFormat-Xcode github page using the tool update_xcode_plugins. All other alcatraz plugins work again, but the ClangFormat plugin does not work. My solution is to use the script from above, remove the save functionality and the delay entries and bind it on a shortcut via Xcodes Behaviours. Now I press CMD+S first, then the shortcut to externally apply clangformat on the current file.